# How can I make inline (i.e., not floating) admonition blocks in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

> [Admonitions](https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material/reference/admonitions/), also known as *call-outs*, are an excellent choice for including side content without significantly interrupting the document flow.

How can I make admonition blocks that are ‘inline’ with surrounding text and *reflow* with it (unlike floating elements such as figures) without having to manually reposition/resize them and adjust spacing every time I change my content?

I know Illustrator might not be best suited for this task.

Thanks.

Comment: You really can't. Illustrator isn't designed for such things. InDesign is.

Comment: @Scott Thank you, I'll see if my work has a license.

Comment: If you are using Creative Cloud and have Illustrator and Photoshop, you have Indesign.  Adobe's current licensing model doesn't really do separate licensing right now.  You can have a license for one program, but if you use more than one, you generally just get the full license which gives you pretty much every Adobe program ever.

Comment: @Alith7 **..for an increased fee** Be aware, if you are paying for *only* Illustrator and *only* Photoshop, there **is** an increase in subscription fees once you need a 3rd application. But after 3.. it's all pretty much the same cost (yearly).

Comment: @Scott you are correct, my apologies!  Last time I actually looked at licensing options, there was not al a carte options other than Photoshop and Acrobat.  You could either get one of those, or the whole lot. Nice to see that they sometimes are capable of listening to the users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really *can't*.

Illustrator is not designed to "anchor" objects to text. In fact, I don't think there are *any* features which even come close to such a thing.

You *can* use Text Wrapping for objects. However that will not allow objects to "flow" with text, should the text change. Like all text wraps, it merely ensure text is aware of the object and won't overlap it.

---

Note, all the above is fairly true for Photoshop as well with the possible exception of text wraps, which Photoshop does *not* do well.

---

**InDesign** has specific features to anchor objects with text and then allow the object to flow with the text when text changes, keeping the object in the same relative position to the text.